# Mapping One to Many on non-primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am doing a code first entity model for the a legacy database (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonID INT PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    PersonSystemID NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
); 

CREATE TABLE Address
(
    AddressID INT PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1),
    PropertyDetails NVARCHAR(255),
    PersonSystemID NVARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonSystemID) REFERENCES Person(PersonSystemID)
)
```

The only interesting detail is that `Address` table is referencing `PersonSystemID` instead of `PersonID` which is the real PK of `Person` table.

I want a property called `Addresses` in the `Person` class, and a property `Person` in the `Address` class.  Is there any way of mapping this? (Fudges and/or cludges are welcome).

Note that this is a readonly database - so I don't need to deal with INSERTS/UPDATES/DELETES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can't, but it will probably be available in future release.

> We are working on unique constraint support in EF7.

http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support

The workaround for now would be removing those navigation properties and manually join the entity.

```
var result = from p in db.Person
             join a in db.Address
             on p.PersonSystemID equals a.PersonSystemID
             select new { Person = p, Address = a };
```